# C# - how to display Datetime Brazilian format (dd/mm/yyyy) on Azure

Tags: azure, date

I have a website running on Azure and the output dates are being displayed in USA format (mm-dd-yyyy). Input dates are being showed in Brazilian format (dd-mm-yyyy) and the dates saved in the database are in Brazilian format too.  When running in Visual Studio, all dates are being displayed correctly (dd-mm-yyyy). The problem is occuring with Edge, Firefox and Chrome. When I check the running code, the dates are in Brazilian format too, but the browsers are converting them to display in USA format. I do not have any instructions on my SDK project related with cultureInfo. I would appreciate it if someone could give me any tips on how to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What type of website is it? You mention it's using C#, but is it ASP.NET Web Forms? MVC Framework? ASP.NET Core? Regardless, you will typically need to set your `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` with the specific `CultureInfo` that you want.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy. My website is based on Razor Pages - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add the following to your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization
            culture="pt-BR"
            uiCulture="pt-BR"
        />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thiago, my website is based on Razor Pages. I will try to add this configuration.

Comment: Thiago, I added a similar code on startup.cs and now is running correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: if it was helpful, vote up and mark as an answer